# DevExpress ASP.NET MVC standalone Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I am new to Dev Express controls and I'm currently trying to work with the Dev Express Filter. In the ASP.NET WebForms edition of Dev Express, the Filter was a separate control which could be configured on it's own. From what I saw so far, for the ASP.NET MVC the Filter is part of the GridView helper.

Is it possible to use only the Filter in a ASP.NET MVC app?

Any links of suggestions are welcomed!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Filter Builder is not available as a standalone MVC Extension ([Implement an analog of ASPxFilterControl](http://www.devexpress.com/scid=Q331803)).

It is only available as a part of the MVC GridView Extension.

Comment: Hi @mikhail! Thank you for your answer! I was rather expecting such an answer, but was hoping I'm wrong and might have missed some links/resources. It's a shame that they don't provide a separate MVC helper for the Filter as that would for sure be very useful...

Comment: You can ping them regarding your request.